# 'used to' & 'had to' ... what tenses are these?

Tags: past-tense, auxiliary-verbs

What are the tenses here? 
*He used to play football professionally, but he had to quit because of an injury.*
The first clause, with 'used to play' and the second clause, with 'had to quit' ... are these both simple past? Is the 'had' an auxiliary verb?

Comment: _Used to_ is past continuous. _Had to_ means _was forced to_ - it's simple past.

Comment: Thanks Kate :) One question about 'used to' being past continuous. This does not use the 'ing' form of the verb. Is the 'ing' form of the verb not necessary in the past continuous?

Comment: Sorry, that was not correct, though _used to_ has the same sense of a continuing action in the past. It's technically a modal verb. https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/used-to_1

Comment: Very interesting Kate ... very interesting. Thanks a ton :)